# Explanation of a bitwise XOR phenomenon

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have found an interesting phenomenon when using bitwise XOR:

$$\begin{array} {ccccc}
134&&   48&&   14\\
\\   
&   182&&  62& \\
\\    
&&    136 &&
\end{array}$$

So the figure above is an or triangle, so 134 or 48 is 182, 48 or 14 is 62, 182 or 62 is 136. What is interesting is I found what I call the "special number" a number that can be used with the numbers above, even though they technically have no relation with each other. So if you do 48 or 136 you get 184, and if you do 14 or 182 you get 184, and if you do 134 or 62 you get 184. So 184 is the special number. Why is it that 184 somehow can be used across the whole triangle? My original goal was to turn the three start numbers into two numbers and using or's get the original three numbers back out. So could you use 184 and another number to find the rest?

I'm curious as to if anyone has seen this before.

Comment: *"182 or 62 is 136"* – So you are talking about bitwise XOR ?

Comment: Yes sorry sometimes I get confused with XOR and OR. Im talking about Bitwise XOR.

Comment: You can edit your question to fix this.  While you're at it, it's spelled "phenomenon".

Answer (score 1):

You're using xor, not or.  I'll denote this by $\oplus$.
Since $(A \oplus B) \oplus (B \oplus C) =A \oplus C$, your triangle is of the form 
$$ \matrix{ A &  & B & & C\cr
             & A \oplus B & & B \oplus C & \cr
             &            &  A \oplus C &  & \cr}$$
and your "special number" is $A \oplus B \oplus C$.